# Не отображаются посты в категории django

Tags: python, django, views, постраничный-вывод

Делаю вывод постов согласно категории. Вывод сделал, а отображается пустая html страница.

***Category.html***

```
{% extends '--/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Статьи в категории - {{ category.name }}{% endblock title %}


 {% if category %}
     {% if posts %}
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">

                                <div class="blog-post">
                                     <div class="blog-post-img">
                                     {% for post in posts %}
                                        {% if post.image %}
                                        <img src="/media/{{ post.image }}"/>
                                        {% endif %}
                                        {% if post.image_url %}
                                        <img src="{{ post.image_url }}">
                                        {% endif %}
                                     </div>
                                 <div class="blog-post-title">
                                       <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
                                     <span>7 августа</span>
                                 </div><!-- // .blog-post-title -->


                                    <div class="blog-post-meta">

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="blog-post-content">
                                        <p>
                                            {{ post.body|safe}}
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="blog-post-more">
                                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i>Читать далее</a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
 {% endif %}
 {% endif %}
```

views

```
 def show_category(request, category_name_slug):
    context_dict = {}
    try:
        category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
        posts = Post.objects.filter(category=category)
        context_dict['posts'] = posts
        context_dict['category'] = category
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        context_dict['category'] = None
        context_dict['posts'] = None
    return render(request, '77/category.html', context_dict)
```

Models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(unidecode(self.name))
        super(Category, self).save()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Категории'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager, self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')


class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_images', blank=True)
    image_url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')
    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail',
                       args=[self.category.slug,
                             self.publish.year,
                             self.publish.strftime('%m'),
                             self.publish.strftime('%d'),
                             self.slug])

    def get_posts(self):
        Post.objects.filter(category=self)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)
        verbose_name_plural = 'Посты'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Вы используете extends, значит должны запихнуть содержимое страницы внутрь какого-нибудь block, который объявлен в base.html. Вы этого не сделали, вот ничего и не выводится

Comment: Спасибо, но это довольно странно вышло. У меня было в блоке и тоже не выводилось, а сейчас всё получилось..

Comment: Значит, возможно, в имени блока опечатались в прошлый раз